# Sorting pandas data frame by date with some rows not having it

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, dataframe

I have such a data frame

`0   1   2
0   240 RSOW    2008-07-11 20:35:00 
1   250 RSOW    2008-06-27 19:10:00
...`

I want to sort it by column 2  by date. But later on same dates look like `\N` and I want to omit those. And the second issue is the format – time and date are in the same column
How can I sort this with pandas without any problems with `\N` and this time thing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this myself.

```
rows = []   
for index, row in subset.iterrows():
    try:
        yr = int(row[2][:4]) # assure it has a numer like year 
        if yr > 2000:
            rows.append(row)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

if it is some kind of NaN like thing for example the `\N` I mentioned then a ValueError will occur and it won't be considered in future analysis.
Next I've simply took the list with rows (`rows`) and with some list comprehension I created a new data frame

```
dic = {"date": [row[2] for row in rows]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df = df.sort_values(by="date")
```

Quite a rookie thing must admit